# AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'site' - wagtail, wagalytics

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm trying to implement wagalytics within my new wagtail site (https://github.com/tomdyson/wagalytics).

I'm my error pops up at line 138 of views.py

```
site = Site.objects.get(hostname=request.site.hostname)
```

> `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'site'`

When I change this to something like

```
try:
    site = Site.objects.get(hostname=request.site.hostname)
except:
    site = '127.0.0.1'
```

It works - or at least gets me onto the next problem.

Obviously I don't want to go chopping in a try/except block into the code in production - and I'd be better off for an understanding of what's happening here and how to resolve it.

Comment: `request.site` does not exists.

Comment: In addition to that ^  what are you trying to access? what should `request.site` contain?

Answer (score 6):

See the [Wagtail 2.9 release notes](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/releases/2.9.html#removed-support-for-django-2-1).  Going forward you should use either `{% wagtail_site %}` or `{{ page.get_site}}` in templates and `Site.find_for_request(request)` in python code.

Answer (score 3):

This error arises because the `request` object has no `.site` attribute. You need to enable the [**`CurrentSiteMiddleware`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware) for that.

You do so by adding `'django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware'` to tuple/list of the `MIDDLEWARE` settings. So the `settings.py` file should look like:

```
# settings.py

# …

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # …,
    'django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware',
    # …
]

# …
```

Comment: One step forwards...I'm now hitting `AttributeError: 'RequestSite' object has no attribute 'hostname'`

Comment: @BenMayo: can you replace `request.site.hostname` with `request.get_host()`? Are you sure you use the latest version? Looks like it uses an old version.

Comment: Thanks Willem - I'll open an issue on GitHub. Will revert back.